RDP only works when my screen is on
On Ubuntu 24.10, I just set up:
System Settings > Remote Desktop > Desktop Sharing
I can now control my computer using another device.
However, whenever I turn off my screen, I can't control my screen anymore, until I turn on my screen again. It seems like the connection gets lost.
How can I fix this? I want to be able to turn off my screen when I'm away.
EDIT: I have read both these questions:

Connect when Remote Desktop is on login screen or screen locked (without autologin)
Maintaining RDP connection to Ubuntu after Ubuntu Screen times out (goes black)

The solutions posted here indeed did work for Ubuntu 24.04, but not for Ubuntu 24.10.

This question is similar to: Connect when Remote Desktop is on login screen or screen locked (without autologin). If you believe it’s different, please [edit] the question, make it clear how it’s different and/or how the answers on that question are not helpful for your problem.

This question is similar to: Maintaining RDP connection to Ubuntu after Ubuntu Screen times out (goes black). If you believe it’s different, please [edit] the question, make it clear how it’s different and/or how the answers on that question are not helpful for your problem.

See update: both these answers did not work for Ubuntu 24.10.
